# Inserting current Database date time via Entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, db2, entity-framework-5

We want to put the current datetime into a database column.

We have a web farm where the time on the web servers can vary, we therefore need to use the datetime on the database server.

We have a database with a `Not Null` datetime column. This column has a default datetime of current time.

This works fine when we insert data using a SQL statement that does not include the datetime column.

From Entity Framework:

- If we define the datetime as `not null`, the datetime is set to low date, and low date is inserted into the database.
- If we define the datetime as `null`, we get an exception on the insert that the value cannot be null.

We could fix this using a database trigger that changed the datetime to current datetime if the insert value is low date.

Does anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the column has a default value set by the database you can simply mark the datetime column as computed:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
property DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

or in fluent mapping

```
this.Property(t => t.Date)
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed);
```

in a `EntityTypeConfiguration` class, or

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyClass>().Property(t => t.Date)
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed);
```

in an `OnModelCreating` override.

This will cause EntityFramework to read the value of the column at each read, insert or update of a record, but it will never set it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will this also work if we have an EDMX file? Will we need to readd the attribute everytime the edmx changes and the code i regenerated?

Comment: In the edmx you can set the `StoreGeneratedPattern` to `Computed` in the property window of a column in the designer. This will survive model updates.

Comment: Thanks, we are using DB2. The DB2 driver did not support "Computed", but we were able to use "Identity". Although it is not an Identity column, it solve the problem of sending low date to the database.

Answer (score -2):

One way is to use UTC dateTime so in C# you can use

```
DateTime.UtcNow
```

You could also set

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
dateTime = SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value;
```

You can even create extension method :

```
public static class DateExtension
    {
        public static DateTime SqlValidDateTime(this DateTime d)
        {
            return SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value;
        }
    }
```

Also for:

> If we define the datetime as null, we get an exception on the insert
>   that the value cannot be null.

You should pass instead of null ->

```
DbNull.Value
```

and then insert should pass.

Comment: It seems from the question of @Shiraz that he want the current DateTime that is in the server database, not the minimum DateTime that is possible to assign...

Comment: @yosoy is correct, this code will read the time from the system clock on the web server, so unfortunatly it does not help