# Entity Framework save server time to database

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I have a Winforms application which runs on Entity Framework and I was wondering how I can save the time on the database server (as opposed to the client machine) to the database.

I have already tried the solution suggested in [Inserting current Database date time via Entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22225701/inserting-current-database-date-time-via-entity-framework) but it doesn't work. When I decorate the properties with the attributes, the values don't even get saved to the database.

Comment: do you want to do this for a single column for every record? Do you want the value updated at any point? I'm assuming SQL Server db?

Comment: Is your column in the DB set to have a default value of the current date because that question is just about getting EF to not set it.

Comment: In my program I have a save function that either updates or inserts a new record depending on whether the record already exists.  I want the time as per the db server saved to the ModifiedDate column (for update) and CreatedDate column (for insert).  No default values are set.  My properties are of type DateTime.

Comment: Which database-provider do you use?

Comment: You didn't read the question you link to carefully enough: *This column has a default datetime of current time*, i.e. a default constraint on the database column.

Comment: I'm just using the .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server

Comment: You could store the UTC time to the database.  It won't matter where the time came from, then, unless you need specific timezone information.

Comment: Did you understand the difference? In the other question the value isn't even *supposed* to be saved by the application. I'd recomend you to do the same thing: use a database default constraint and, if necessary, a trigger to update the value on updates. This is common practice when it comes to setting database date/time values. There's really no point in pulling the exact database time into the application, let it sit there for a random amount of time and then save it somewhere.

Comment: I just want to make sure I understand this correctly since this is new turf for me.  So do you mean set my 2 datetime columns to use a default value of the current date/time using `GetDate()` and decorate my CreatedDate property with the `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` attribute and the ModifiedDate column with the `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]` attribute and do not include these columns in my insert/update queries

Comment: H.Tran correct. You could solve this this way. You can configure your model and column on EF so the values are auto generated by SQL Server. When you do database-update, it will update your column and add a default value for it. But, as Amy said.. it is better for you to use UTC and not the dates on the database... this is a more robust and future proof solution.

Comment: So I added a default constraint to the ModifiedDate column using the query

`ALTER TABLE [NormalTemplateVR_Edit]
ADD CONSTRAINT dfC_ModifiedDate
DEFAULT GetDate() FOR [ModifiedDate]`

and added the `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]` attribute to the ModifiedDate property and excluded the ModifiedDate property from the Save function and this column does not get updated when I update the table